# packages in certain version missing in official repo of different distribution system as system rolling update

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, repository

#### problem description:

I was going to install foreman=1.14.3 which need rh-ruby22-ruby as it's dependency but i can not find rh-ruby22-ruby in repo centos-sclo-rh as `yum info rh-ruby22-ruby` tells me that it ought to be there as below content tells the story

```
[root@rnoaz02ppm01 /]# yum info rh-ruby22-ruby
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
Name        : rh-ruby22-ruby
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.2.2
Release     : 16.el7
Size        : 69 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : centos-sclo-rh
Summary     : An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language
URL         : http://ruby-lang.org/
License     : (Ruby or BSD) and Public Domain and MIT and CC0 and zlib and UCD
Description : Ruby is the interpreted scripting language for quick and easy
            : object-oriented programming.  It has many features to process text
            : files and to do system management tasks (as in Perl).  It is simple,
            : straight-forward, and extensible.
```

also i searched google and luckily i found https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=13739 where i can find the rpm package, but the package still need dependency as below shows:

```
[root@slc07ppm02 yum.repos.d]# rpm -i https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/rh-ruby22-ruby/2.2.2/15.el7/x86_64/rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libruby.so.2.2()(64bit) is needed by rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64
    rh-ruby22-ruby(rubygems) >= 2.4.5 is needed by rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64
    rh-ruby22-ruby-libs(x86-64) = 2.2.2-15.el7 is needed by rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64
    rh-ruby22-rubygem(bigdecimal) >= 1.2.6 is needed by rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64
    rh-ruby22-runtime is needed by rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64
```

#### Questions:

1. Did i do the wrong staff by trying `rpm -i https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/rh-ruby22-ruby/2.2.2/15.el7/x86_64/rh-ruby22-ruby-2.2.2-15.el7.x86_64.rpm`, may be i could try other staff in the page.
2. Any where that i can download the rpm packages with full dependencies?
3. What if i really want the rmp package what can i do?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: install it with command `yum install rh-ruby22-ruby`

Comment: @Romeo [the Ruby 2.2 SCL](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-ruby22/) is no longer available (it reached EOL in April 2018) so that won’t work.

Comment: Do linux community have ways to maintain the old release of the software?